# VIM comment out on blade files

Tags: laravel, vim, nerdcommenter

How can I toggle comments on blade.php extension files.

Blade is a Laravel specific file which uses {{-- --}} to comment out.

I installed Nerdcommenter but, don't know how to modify it to work with blade files due to the lack of Vim knowledge

Now, when I comment out the plugin uses

```
<!-- -->
```

Does anyone know how to set the thing up or recommend me other plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nerdcommenter [already have the comment style you mention](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/dcd63ec0268db7089df0c1dc084d112a4c5a8cd6/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim#L235), but you need to be using the filetype `laravel` for it to work properly.

Try issuing `:set ft=laravel` before using nerdcommenter again.

To make this work everytime you edit a blade file, you can include the following line in your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.blade.php set filetype=laravel
```

You probably also need to ensure that you have `filetype indent plugin on` in your `vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment sir.I added it to my vimrc file.But, it won't work

Comment: You have to use the command after you open the file. Vim will try to guess the filetype as you open a file, and since the extension is `php`, it'll default to the `php` filetype.

Comment: After I open the blade file and type the command in vim.It worked thx.But,after I close Vim it no longer works.How can I make it permanent?Thank you for helping me really

Comment: What's the name of your files like? Do they end with `.blade.php`?

Comment: Yes.it's like {filename}.blade.php

Comment: Try putting this in your `vimrc`: `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.blade.php set filetype=laravel`

Comment: Thanks @rgolivaira I added autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.blade.php set filetype=laravel.But no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121900/discussion-between-rgoliveira-and-shigg).

Comment: Looks like filetype needs to be "blade", this way it works with both vim-blade and nerdcommenter